# error in installation of xournal

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

```
root@bt:~# sudo apt-get install xournal

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

  g++: Depends: cpp (>= 4:4.7.2-1) but 4:4.4.3-1ubuntu1 is to be installed

       Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.7.2-1) but 4:4.4.3-1ubuntu1 is to be installed

       Depends: g++-4.7 (>= 4.7.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed

       Depends: gcc-4.7 (>= 4.7.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed

  google-chrome-stable: Depends: gconf-service but it is not going to be installed

                        Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.23)
                        Depends: libgconf-2-4 (>= 2.31.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5) but 1.4.4-5ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libnspr4 (>= 1.8.0.10) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libnss3 (>= 3.14.3) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.3.2-1ubuntu3 is to be installed

  xournal: Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) but 2.8.0-2ubuntu1 is to be installed

           Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libpoppler-glib8 (>= 0.18) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: ghostscript-x but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

I am using

```
root@bt:~# uname -a
Linux bt 3.2.6 #1 SMP Fri Feb 17 10:34:20 EST 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@bt:~# lsb_release -sc
lucid
```

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get -f install xournal`

Comment: sorry it did't worked same output.

Answer (score 0):

## Run these following commands to install xournal in Lucid

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add the following line in `sources.list` file

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian squeeze main universe
```

save the `sources.list` file and update the repositories by running the below command,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install `xournal` by running the below command,

```
sudo apt-get install xournal
```

This will install xournal and its dependencies.

## Run the following commands to uninstall xournal in Lucid

uninstall xournal only

```
sudo apt-get purge xournal
```

uninstall xournal and its dependencies

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove xournal
```

Comment: dear it give same error on running  sudo apt-get install xournal